# Rails - how would you set up this HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-key-relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a situation where `Project` can have many `Tags` (and vice versa), so I have set up a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between the two.

My question is this: I need a project to have the ability to carry a single **current** tag.

#### Option 1

Can I add a `tag_id` to my Project table? How do I set up the relationship correctly, given there is already a `projects_tags' model?

#### Option 2

I'd imagine it isn't effective to have the projects_tags model carry a boolean `current` field, because it would require additional queries in practice for me to find the right relationship. I just throw it out there as an alternative I've considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :current_tag, :class_name => Tag
end
```

And then have `current_tag_id` in your `projects` table.

You can't add `current` to `projects_tags` because it's not technically a model: it's only a join table. You'd have to incorporate another model and use `has_many :through` to do it that way.

Comment: Dan, does that mean I can have both HABTM and belongs_to relationships between Project and Tag?

Comment: Of course! You just need to make sure that they're not the same name, which is why I used `current_tag` rather than just `tag` in my example above.

Comment: Question - if there are two relationships and I then call `Tag.projects.where...`, how can I specify which relationship to use?

Comment: You'd need to make sure that the relationship definition in `Tag` that corresponds to `Project.current_tag` is named something else, perhaps `current_projects`